# Coins are pretty easy to be found/to find

Tags: infinitives

I have this assumption: we can use either passive or active infinitives when there isn't the agent in the sentence and the characteristic belongs to the very thing, for example:

> This jalapeno is too spicy to be eaten(the jalapeno itself is spicy)

However, when the characteristic doesn't belong to the thing itself, we can only use active infinitives, e.g:

> Coins are pretty easy to find on the ground(not the coins are easy; the finding of them is easy)

But maybe I'm wrong and we can say:

> Coins are pretty easy to be found on the ground.

So, please, let me know whether I have failed or not.

Comment: To create a paragraph leave a blank line.  To insert a quote use the >  character. Don't use the bullet character, that doesn't work.  Please proofread and spell check.

Comment: I'd say that's a pretty good rule.

Answer (score -1):

The function word *to* plus a verb **implies a purpose** or end result.

She wore that outfit to be seen by her friends.

Ergo, coins are not "easy to be found"; *coins are easily found* on the ground.

The jalapeño is too spicy to eat. [a general statement]

These jalapeños **are too spicy to be eaten by children**.

Comment: Lambie, What do you mean by the phrase "to plus a verb"? That is an expression I am not familiar with.

Comment: the function word *to* + a verb. like to see, going to go, seeming to be. It is not an expression; it is just a way to describe a type of structure.